# ByteBuffer.allocate() vs. ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()

Tags: java, performance, nio, bytebuffer

To `allocate()` or to `allocateDirect()`, that is the question.

For some years now I've just stuck to the thought that since `DirectByteBuffer`s are a direct memory mapping at OS level, that it would perform quicker with get/put calls than `HeapByteBuffer`s. I never was really interested in finding out the exact details regarding the situation until now. I want to know which of the two types of `ByteBuffer`s are faster and on what conditions.

Comment: To give a specific answer, you need to say specificly what you are doing with them.  If one was always faster than the other, why would there be two variants.  Perhaps you can expand on why you are now "really interested in finding out the exact details" BTW: Have you read the code, esp for DirectByteBuffer?

Comment: They will be used to read from and write to `SocketChannel`s that are configured for non-blocking. So regarding what @bmargulies said, `DirectByteBuffer`s will perform faster for the channels.

Comment: @Gnarly At least the current version of my answer says that channels are expected to benefit.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Ron Hitches in his excellent book [Java NIO](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596002882) seems to offer what I thought could be a good answer to your question:

> Operating systems perform I/O
>   operations on memory areas. These
>   memory areas, as far as the operating
>   system is concerned, are contiguous
>   sequences of bytes. It's no surprise
>   then that only byte buffers are
>   eligible to participate in I/O
>   operations. Also recall that the 
>   operating system will directly access
>   the address space of the process, in
>   this case the JVM process, to transfer
>   the data. This means that memory areas
>   that are targets of I/O perations must
>   be contiguous sequences of bytes. In
>   the JVM, an array of bytes may not be
>   stored contiguously in memory, or the
>   Garbage Collector could move it at any
>   time. Arrays are objects in Java, and
>   the way data is stored inside that
>   object could vary from one JVM
>   implementation to another.
>
> For this reason, the notion of a
>   direct buffer was introduced. Direct
>   buffers are intended for interaction
>   with channels and native I/O routines.
>   They make a best effort to store the
>   byte elements in a memory area that a
>   channel can use for direct, or raw,
>   access by using native code to tell
>   the operating system to drain or fill
>   the memory area directly.
>
> Direct byte buffers are usually the
>   best choice for I/O operations. By
>   design, they support the most
>   efficient I/O mechanism available to
>   the JVM. Nondirect byte buffers can be
>   passed to channels, but doing so may
>   incur a performance penalty. It's
>   usually not possible for a nondirect
>   buffer to be the target of a native
>   I/O operation. If you pass a nondirect
>   ByteBuffer object to a channel for
>   write, the channel may implicitly do
>   the following on each call:
>
> 1. Create a temporary direct ByteBuffer
>      object.
> 2. Copy the content of the nondirect
>      buffer to the temporary buffer.
> 3. Perform the low-level I/O operation
>      using the temporary buffer.
> 4. The temporary buffer object goes out
>      of scope and is eventually garbage
>      collected.
>
> This can potentially result in buffer
>   copying and object churn on every I/O,
>   which are exactly the sorts of things
>   we'd like to avoid. However, depending
>   on the implementation, things may not
>   be this bad. The runtime will likely
>   cache and reuse direct buffers or
>   perform other clever tricks to boost
>   throughput. If you're simply creating
>   a buffer for one-time use, the
>   difference is not significant. On the
>   other hand, if you will be using the
>   buffer repeatedly in a
>   high-performance scenario, you're
>   better off allocating direct buffers
>   and reusing them.
>
> Direct buffers are optimal for I/O,
>   but they may be more expensive to
>   create than nondirect byte buffers.
>   The memory used by direct buffers is
>   allocated by calling through to
>   native, operating system-specific
>   code, bypassing the standard JVM heap.
>   Setting up and tearing down direct
>   buffers could be significantly more
>   expensive than heap-resident buffers,
>   depending on the host operating system
>   and JVM implementation. The
>   memory-storage areas of direct buffers
>   are not subject to garbage collection
>   because they are outside the standard
>   JVM heap.
>
> The performance tradeoffs of using
>   direct versus nondirect buffers can
>   vary widely by JVM, operating system,
>   and code design. By allocating memory
>   outside the heap, you may subject your
>   application to additional forces of
>   which the JVM is unaware. When
>   bringing additional moving parts into
>   play, make sure that you're achieving
>   the desired effect. I recommend the
>   old software maxim: first make it
>   work, then make it fast. Don't worry
>   too much about optimization up front;
>   concentrate first on correctness. The
>   JVM implementation may be able to
>   perform buffer caching or other
>   optimizations that will give you the
>   performance you need without a lot of
>   unnecessary effort on your part.

Comment: I don't like that quote because it contains too much guessing.  Also, the JVM certainly does not need to allocate a direct ByteBuffer when doing IO for a non direct ByteBuffer: it's sufficient to malloc a sequence of bytes on the heap, do the IO, copy from the bytes to the ByteBuffer and release the bytes.  Those areas could even be cached.  But it is totally unnecessary to allocate a Java object for this.

Real answers will only be obtained from measuring.  Last time I did measurements there was no significant difference.  I would have to redo tests to come up with all the specific details.

Comment: It is questionable if a book that describes NIO (and native operations) can have certainties in it. After all, different JVMs and operating systems manage things differently, so the author cannot be blamed for being unable to guarantee certain behavior.

Comment: @RobertKlemme, +1, we all hate the guesswork, However, it may be impossible to measure performance for all major OSes, since there's just way too many major OSes. [Another post](http://goo.gl/X67Ot8)  attempted that, but we can see [many many problems](http://goo.gl/K5dU9G) with it's benchmark, starting with "the results fluctuate widely depending on the OS".  Also, what if there's a black sheep that do horrible stuff like buffer copying on every I/O? Then because of that sheep, we may be forced to prevent writing code we would otherwise use, *just* to avoid these worst-case scenarios.

Comment: @RobertKlemme I agree. There is far too much guesswork here. The JVM is vanishingly unlikely to allocate byte arrays sparsely, for example.

Comment: @Edwin Dalorzo : Why do we need such byte buffer in real world? Are they invented as a hack to share memory between the process? Say for example JVM runs on a process and it would be another process which runs on network or data link layer - which is responsible for transmitting the data - are these byte buffers allocated to share memory between these processes? Please correct me if i'm wrong..

Answer (score 29):

There is no reason to expect direct buffers to be faster for access *inside* the jvm. Their advantage comes when you pass them to native code -- such as, the code behind channels of all kinds.

Comment: Indeed. Like, when need to do IO in Scala/Java and call embedded Python / native libs with large in memory data for algorithmic processing or feed data directly to a GPU in Tensorflow.

Answer (score 25):

> since DirectByteBuffers are a direct
>   memory mapping at OS level

They aren't. They are just normal application process memory, but not subject to relocation during Java GC which simplifies things inside the JNI layer considerably. What you describe applies to `MappedByteBuffer`.

> that it would perform quicker with get/put calls

The conclusion doesn't follow from the premiss; the premiss is false; and the conclusion is also false. They are faster once you get inside the JNI layer, and if you are reading and writing from the same `DirectByteBuffer` they are *much* faster, because the data never has to cross the JNI boundary at all.

Comment: This is a good and important point: on the path of IO you have to cross the Java - JNI border at *some* point.  Direct and non direct byte buffers only move the border: with a direct buffer all put operations from Java land have to cross, while with a non direct buffer all IO operations have to cross.  What is faster depends on the application.

Comment: @RobertKlemme Your summary is incorrect. With all buffers, any data coming to and from Java has to cross the JNI boundary. The point of direct buffers is that if you are just copying the data from one channel to another, e.g. uploading a file, you don't have to get it into Java at all, which is much faster.

Comment: where exactly is my summary incorrect?  And what "summary" to begin with?  I was explicitly talking about "put operations from Java land".  If you only copy data around between Channels (i.e. never have to deal with the data in Java land) that's a different story of course.

Comment: @RobertKlemme Your statement that 'with a direct buffer [only] all put operations from Java land have to cross' is incorrect. Both gets and puts have to cross.

Comment: EJP, you're apparently still missing the intended distinction @RobertKlemme was making by choosing to use the words "put operations" in one phrase and using the words "IO operations" in the contrasted phrase of the sentence. In the latter phrase, his intention was to refer to operations between the buffer and an OS-provided device of some kind.

Answer (score 21):

Best to do your own measurements. Quick answer seems to be that sending from an `allocateDirect()` buffer takes 25% to 75% less time than the `allocate()` variant (tested as copying a file to /dev/null), depending on size, but that the allocation itself can be *significantly* slower (even by a factor of 100x).

Sources:

- [Why the odd performance curve differential between ByteBuffer.allocate() and ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651737/why-the-odd-performance-curve-differential-between-bytebuffer-allocate-and-byte)
- [ByteBuffer.allocateDirect ridiculously slow](http://community.jboss.org/thread/82231)
- [When to use Array, Buffer or direct Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18913001/632951)

Comment: Thanks. I would accept your answer but I'm looking for some more specific details regarding the differences in performance.