# how to map with jna a byte[] to a void* buffer?

Tags: java, c, jna

I have the following C function:

```
    int read(int dev, void* buffer, unsigned int count)
```

This is usually call in C like:

```
    read(data->dev, data->buffer, 32000);
```

data is a struct, with the following:

```
    typedef struct {
         ssize_t dev; 
         char buffer[32000]; 
    } DATA;
```

And I have convert this to java, with jna with the following:

```
    public class Data{//not neccesary to extends of Structure, because is only used to package both variables together
          public int dev;
          public byte[] buffer;//in the constructor of the class set to 32000 elements
    }

   int read(int playdev, Buffer buffer, int count);

   //clib is the class to connect with  de C library

   ByteBuffer bf = ByteBuffer.wrap(data.buffer);
   clib.read(data.dev, bf , READ_SIZE);
```

And it gives me a "java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access" when I do the "clib.read"

Any idea how to go through this error???

I have tried to make a:
        int vox_playstr_read(int playdev, Pointer buffer, int count);

with

```
    ByteBuffer bf = ByteBuffer.wrap(data.buffer);
    Pointer pbuf = Native.getDirectBufferPointer(bf);
    clib.read(data.dev, pbuf, READ_SIZE);
```

and it gives me the same result.

Please, any ideas to make it work?

Comment: You can pass the `byte[]` directly, use an NIO buffer, or use JNA `Memory`.  JNA supports all three as buffer-type arguments.

Comment: Please update your question with your *actual* code.  You do not indicate how you've initialized `buf` or `data.buffer`; that could very well be where your error lies.

Comment: I have edited the answer. With "buf", I mean "bf", its the same, I create the buffer and build de pointer with it. I have tried with byte[] directly, but not with Memory, and I don't know how you say it can apply here.

Comment: `Native.getDirectBufferAddress()` does not work with an NIO buffer wrapping a primitive array.  Use `bf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size)` instead.  At any rate you should be able to pass the `ByteBuffer` directly to the `read` function; you should also be able to pass `byte[]` directly to `read`.  Add debugging to your C function to spit out the arguments it's receiving; if the arguments are incorrect, then you've likely got the calling convention or signature wrong.

Comment: in the answer below of Radical, I said I tried with bf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size), with the same result. And I can't debug de C function, because it's in a *.dll and I don't have access to the real C code.... But it's suppoused to be tested and whatever, so I assumed it's ok, and the problem was in my side...

Comment: If your DLL is using the `stdcall` calling convention, or if the sizes of its arguments are different than what you convey (int, pointer, int), then you'll wind up with incorrect parameter values.  You're also calling `read` from the C library, which is distinctly different from `vox_playstr_read`.

Comment: Sorry, I misplaced the function, I have edited the post now.

Comment: `msvcrt.dll` (Microsoft's C runtime library) does not export a `read` function (the one you are looking for is named `_read`).  You may be picking up a different `read` than the one you're looking for.

Comment: its not the msvcrt.dll library the one I'm exporting with JNA. It's from another dll and I'm pretty sure the parameters are ok. But thank you for the point.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the ByteBuffer with [ByteBuffer.allocateDirect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#allocateDirect%28int%29) and then use byteBuffer.put(..) if you want to set any initial data. Also, reset the position of the buffer, buffer.position(0).

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(values.length);
bb.put(values);
bb.position(0);
```

Read Edwin's reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670862/bytebuffer-allocate-vs-bytebuffer-allocatedirect) for the reason to use allocateDirect.

Comment: I tried it with ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(32000);
      buf.put(data.buffer); and the result was the same a "java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access"

Comment: .. and you reset the position to 0, with buf.position(0), and data.buffer.length == 32000 ? You could test with a simple function which gets such a pointer and tries to put few bytes there, which you can check on the java side, after that native function returns.

Comment: With your modification the result is the same exception as before :(

Comment: I was reasearching this today and found this question. You must remember the difference in endiannes between the JVM and the underlying machine. I would use `ByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())` immediately after allocation.

Answer (score 0):

technomage's comments to the original post are exactly right. Explicitly, on the Java side, declare your JNA interface method as you plan to use it:

```
int read(int playdev, byte[] buffer, int count);

clib.read(data.dev, data.buffer, READ_SIZE);
```

No need to use Buffer or ByteBuffer. Also, depending on whether the read function is exported __cdecl or __stdcall, your JNA interface should `extends Library` or `extends StdCallLibrary` respectively.