# What is the difference(s) between ByteBuffer modes?

Tags: java, io, nio

I just interested about the difference between these two guys
`ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4)`
and
`ByteBuffer.allocate(4)`

and why when I call the `array()` method of direct one, it throws exception? what is the difference? would you provide a simple example and usage too? many thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670862/bytebuffer-allocate-vs-bytebuffer-allocatedirect

Answer (score 0):

> When I call the array() method of direct one, it throws exception?  What is the difference?

A `HeapByteBuffer` (from `allocate()`), is backed by an array, but a `DirectByteBuffer` (from `allocateDirect()`) is backed by an block of unmanaged memory, which it accesses directly.  It has no backing array, and thus calling `array()` will throw.

The question @Vakh links to in his comment explains the differences nicely.