# Buffer types for MessageToByteEncoder in Netty

Tags: java, netty

I've been reading Norman Maurer's [presentation on Netty best practices](http://normanmaurer.me/presentations/2014-twitter-meetup-netty/slides.html) and had a question about using direct buffers versus heap buffers. [One slide](http://normanmaurer.me/presentations/2014-twitter-meetup-netty/slides.html#13.0) recommends "always use direct ByteBuffer when writing to SocketChannel," but [another](http://normanmaurer.me/presentations/2014-twitter-meetup-netty/slides.html#25.0) encourages using heap buffers when using `MessageToByteEncoder`. I don't think I quite get the nuances in the second slide; in the `MessageToByteEncoder` case, why does using heap buffers "save extra byte copies?"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using heap-buffers may make sense if you need to act directly on the backing array. This is for example true when you use deflater/inflater as it only acts on byte[]. For all other cases a direct buffer is prefered.

Comment: Lucky you...an answer from the man himself :).  Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5671880/3993966 for a good general description of the differences between direct and non-direct buffers in java.