# Pre-allocate buffer for call to SWIG generated C bridge from Java?

Tags: java, java-native-interface, swig

I have a simple `C` library that I use from `Java`. The bridge is fully working. However, one of the methods requires an array, resulting in unwanted memory allocation/deallocation.

`SWIG` code:

```
typedef struct {} Foo;
%apply short[] {const int16 *FOODATA};

%extend Foo {
    Foo(size_t bufferSize, int *errcode) {

        /* WHAT TO DO WITH BUFFER SIZE?? */

        Foo *foo = foo_create();
        *errcode = foo ? 0 : -1;
        return foo;
    }

    ~Foo() {
        foo_free($self);
    }

    void bar(const int16 *FOODATA, size_t FOOSIZE, int *errcode) {
        *errcode = foo_bar($self, FOODATA, FOOSIZE);
    }
}
```

`Java` code:

```
final int bufferSize = 32768;
final short[] bar = new short[bufferSize];
Foo foo = new Foo(bufferSize);
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    // Fill bar with at most 32768 beers...
    // ...

    foo.bar(bar, bar.length);
}
```

This works but each call to `bar()` implies an allocation using `malloc()` and a subsequent deallocation using `free()` - in `SWIG` generated code. Obviously, this is a waste of resources.

**How can I avoid the temporary memory allocation/deallocation for my array** sent to `foo_bar()`?

Obviously, the buffer size is known beforehand so it should be possible to *pre-allocate* a buffer and tell `SWIG` to use that.

Comment: Somebody somewhere has to allocate the memory for it. Are you hoping to have the `Foo` constructor do the allocation for you and make it usable from Java?

Comment: I solved it using `java.nio.ByteBuffer`.

Comment: That's a pretty good solution by the sounds of things - care to write it up as an answer for others?

Comment: I ended up using `ByteBuffer` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32474455/419761).