# `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect` and Xmx

Tags: java, memory-management

According to [various](http://blog.asquareb.com/blog/2015/06/05/java-direct-bytebuffer-performance-advantages-and-considerations/) [sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5671880/5899161) (though not specifically mentioned in JavaDoc), `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect` allocates the memory off the main JVM heap. I can confirm that using Java Mission Control, seeing that the program that calls `ByteBuffer n = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(Integer.MAX_VALUE)` does not use much of Java Heap memory:

[image]

However, this off-heap memory allocation stops working when one limits JVM heap memory. For example, when I run the JVM with `-Xmx1g` option, the `allocateDirect` call causes the following exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory`. I do not fully understand how can this JVM option pertain to off-heap direct memory allocation, as - according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html) - the `-Xmx` option sets the Java heap space size. If I allocate the memory using `getUnsafe().allocateMemory(Integer.MAX_VALUE);` the memory is allocated successfully. My JVM is as follows:

> java version "10" 2018-03-20 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3
>   (build 10+46) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10+46,
>   mixed mode)

Is this kind of behaviour between `Xmx` and `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect` expected?

EDIT: There seemed to be a (non-reproducible) [bug](https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8145536) in JDK 1.7 with the same behaviour as described above. So is this a bug?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had to go on a scavenger hunt to find the reason, but here you go!

First, I looked at `ByteBuffer#allocateDirect` and found the following:

```
public static ByteBuffer allocateDirect(int capacity) {
    return new DirectByteBuffer(capacity);
}
```

I then navigated to the constructor of `DirectByteBuffer` and found the following method call:

```
Bits.reserveMemory(size, cap);
```

Looking in this method, we see:

```
while (true) {
    if (tryReserveMemory(size, cap)) {
        return;
    }

    if (sleeps >= MAX_SLEEPS) {
        break;
    }

    try {
        if (!jlra.waitForReferenceProcessing()) {
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            sleepTime <<= 1;
            sleeps++;
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        interrupted = true;
    }
}

// no luck
throw new OutOfMemoryError("Direct buffer memory");
```

This seems to be where you received this error, but now we need to figure out why it's caused.  For that, I looked into the call to `tryReserveMemory` and found the following:

```
private static boolean tryReserveMemory(long size, int cap) {
    long totalCap;

    while (cap <= maxMemory - (totalCap = totalCapacity.get())) {
        if (totalCapacity.compareAndSet(totalCap, totalCap + cap)) {
            reservedMemory.addAndGet(size);
            count.incrementAndGet();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I was curious about the `maxMemory` field, and looked to where it was declared:

```
private static volatile long maxMemory = VM.maxDirectMemory();
```

Now I had to look at the `maxDirectMemory` within `VM.java`:

```
public static long maxDirectMemory() {
    return directMemory;
}
```

Finally, let's look at the declaration of `directMemory`:

```
// A user-settable upper limit on the maximum amount of allocatable direct
// buffer memory.  This value may be changed during VM initialization if
// "java" is launched with "-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=<size>".
//
// The initial value of this field is arbitrary; during JRE initialization
// it will be reset to the value specified on the command line, if any,
// otherwise to Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory().
//
private static long directMemory = 64 * 1024 * 1024;
```

Hey, look at that!  If you don't manually specify this using `"-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=<size>"`, then it defaults to `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()`, which is the heap size that you set.

Seeing as `-Xmx1G` is smaller than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` bytes, the call to `tryReserveMemory` will **never** return `true`, which results in `sleeps >= MAX_SLEEPS`, breaking out of the while-loop, throwing your `OutOfMemoryError`.

If we look at `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()`, then we see why it works if you **don't** specify the max heap size:

```
/**
 * Returns the maximum amount of memory that the Java virtual machine
 * will attempt to use.  If there is no inherent limit then the value
 * {@link java.lang.Long#MAX_VALUE} will be returned.
 *
 * @return  the maximum amount of memory that the virtual machine will
 *          attempt to use, measured in bytes
 * @since 1.4
 */
public native long maxMemory();
```

Comment: This is awesome, Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Well, this is not a bug, let me tell you why the `allocateDirect` causes `OOM`.
In JVM, you already know `-Xmx` option that sets the Max JVM Heap Size. But you have to know that JVM Memory(heap) is also a part of your PC memory. 
In simple terms, this means `Your PC Memory` = `JVM` + `Direct Memory`.
So when you set JVM option to '-Xmx1g' and get `OOM` exception, check be sure you have enough memory(the rest of your PC memory) to run `allocateDirect`.

Hope it will help you!