# ArrayList<Short> to direct ShortBuffer (java)

Tags: java, arraylist, buffer

The Problem: I collect a unknown number of `shorts` into a `ArrayList<Short>`. When finished I need to put it into a `direct ShortBuffer`.

My Solution: Writing a simple loop.

But in my final Code, this will be done only once and it is not timecritical. In such a case, I always prefer a solution that needs less code.

Can it be done in a one or two liner?

Edit:

With `ArrayList<Short>.toArray` I can get a `Short[]` array, but for `ShortBuffer.put()` I need a `short[]`array. That is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
short[] shortArray = IntStream.range(0, array.length)
    .collect(() -> new short[array.length], (b, i) -> b[i] = array[i], null);
```

I think will work for converting a `Short[]` to `short[]`, as long as it doesn't contain null values. Or you can use [apache commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) which has the `toPrimitive` method do to this.

Also, [When to use Array, Buffer or direct Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18913001/when-to-use-array-buffer-or-direct-buffer) :unless there is a really special reason for using direct buffer you probably shouldn't.